# HTML: Trying to get inner div from outer div and place that div outside of outer div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get inner div from outer div and placing that inner div outside of outer div.

[image]

```
<div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
<div class="vc_gitem_row.............."></div>
<div>
```

I Want to get :

```
<div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
<div>

<div class="vc_gitem_row.............."></div>
```

Is it possible to do that by css or jquery..?

Comment: It sure is. Where's your attempt? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Its html generated by visual composer (wordpress). I am in a situation where I want to get inner div and place outside of outer div.. I am doing css but not getting the proper results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the `div` using `$('div')` then replace it *after* the element using [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```js
// Get div you want to move
var inner = $(".inner");

// replace div
$(".outer").after(inner);

// DOM after above code has been executed
//
// <div class="outer"></div>
// <div class="inner">inner div</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">inner div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I will try this and then inform to you.

Comment: Basically don't want to replace the outer div with inner div but want to place the inner div after the outer div

Comment: The code doens't replace the outer with the inner. It places the inner div after the outer div.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) for this purpose, you don't need to split the process into remove/add, it will do that in one step, like this:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('.vc_gitem-zone-mini').after($('.vc_gitem_row'));
});
```

```css
.vc_gitem-zone-mini{
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

.vc_gitem_row{
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vc_gitem-zone-mini">
<div class="vc_gitem_row"></div>
</div>

<button>LEAVE!</button>
```

Comment: Ok, I will try this and then inform you